# MySQL - Random 'A' from Random 'B'

Tags: mysql, random

From a MySQL table holding records of quotations and their authors (with corresponding unique IDs), I want to select a random record. Simple.

Imagine, though, that I have **100** quotes from Shakespeare and only **10 each** from other authors.

Without using arbitrary weighting, how can I get a random `author_id`, *then* pull a random `quote_id` which has that `author_id`?

(I did this in MSSQL, but am new to MySQL and couldn't find any similar case of *Random from Random*.)
(Note: This is a relatively small table, so `Order by RAND()` is fine.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do this, it should pick one author at random and then from that authors quotes pick one at random.

```
select quotes.* 
  from quotes, 
       (select author 
          from quotes 
         group by author 
         order by rand() 
         limit 1) random_author 
 where quotes.author=random_author.author 
 order by rand() limit 1;
```

Ps, best solution might be to normalize this data into two tables, one for authors and one for quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You could first select a random author from a distinct list of authors and assign it to a variable `@randomAuthor`. This gives you an even distribution. Afterwards, simply select a quote from that author. This is probably not the most efficient way to do it, but at least it'll work.

```
SET @randomAuthor
      = (SELECT DISTINCT author_id
           FROM quotes
           ORDER BY RAND()
           LIMIT 1);

SELECT quote_id
  FROM quotes
  WHERE author_id = @randomAuthor
  ORDER BY RAND()
  LIMIT 1;
```